# Getting KeyError while iterating object names using locals()

Tags: python, locals

I have 5 objects, `mac5_le()`, `mac4_le` and so on. I am trying to extract some value from each of the objects as follows,

```
for i in range(5,-1,-1):
     m = locals()['self.mac'+str(i)+'_le.text()']
     print m
```

I am getting the error as `KeyError: 'self.mac5_le.text()'.`

Any Idea?

Comment: Can you give more context - what are you trying to do, and why have you resorted to doing strange things with `locals()`?

Comment: Dear DBR, sorry for not replying since i was stuck in some other loop. I have objects of similar name and wanted to loop through their names. but they are constructed in the parent class. **getattr** is also not working. Kindly help. -- Manjunath Bhat

Comment: m = getattr(self, 'mac%d_le' % i).text() works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What the what?

```
m = getattr(self, 'mac%d_le' % i).text()
```

Comment: Dear Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, sorry for not replying since i was stuck in a different loop. Your answer works perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why you would want to munge objects around that way, but you've definitely got your syntax wrong:

```
locals()['self.mac'+str(i)+'_le'].text()
```

should "work".

Comment: Hello Tim Pietzcker, sorry for not replying since I fell into some other loop. The answer you told works fine but in my case i'm playing with the methods of parent class. Anyways thanks a lot for the quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few things wrong with what you're attempting.  First, `self.name` variables are not local scope.  They're either part of the instance, or part of the class.  Locals are variables that are accessible from your current function scope, but not the global scope.  For instance, in the code below, you would see `foo` and `bar`, but not `baz`:

```
baz = 1

def silly():
    # These two variables are local
    foo = 2
    bar = 3
    print locals()
```

Calling `silly()`:

```
>>> silly()
{'foo': 2, 'bar': 3}
```

Secondly, the `locals()` and `globals()` dictionaries don't resolve the dot operator, nor will they call functions.

What you want to do is use something like `getattr`, or create an api that works better for you (the code you're trying to write isn't very idiomatic Python).  Here's what is might look like with `getattr`:

```
for i in range(5,-1,-1):
    m = getattr(self, 'mac'+str(i)+'_le').text()
    print m
```

`getattr` is will do all the right lookups underneath the hood to find `macN_le`.  Once you have a reference to the object, then you can call `.text()` on it.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Dear jszakmeister, Sorry for not replying since I fell into some other loop. Since I'm using the methods of the parent class, **getattr** is also not working. :( Anyways thanks a lot for your quick reply.

Comment: again syntax mistake. u have suggested the correct answer. it perfectly works. Thanks a lot.